# Function to use with glue package to replace a space with a new line

Tags: r

I want to replace every space with a new line whilst still using the glue package, I know I can do this by using `\n` as exampled below but it would be more efficient within a function.

```
library(glue)
glue("hello world hello world") #what I am starting with
glue("hello\nworld\nhello\nworld") #what I want the end result to be
```

Any suggestions for a function that can insert a new line at every space whilst still using the glue function?

Comment: Replacing arbitrary characters with another character isn't really a `glue` thing, people normally use `gsub` or `stringr::str_replace_all`. Like `gsub(pattern = " ", replacement = "\\n", x = your_string)`. It's not clear what you want the `glue` function to do or why you want to still use it - you could certainly wrap it, `glue(gsub(...))`

Comment: @GregorThomas, I think it should be `replacement="\n"` (single backslash).

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do this with `glue` for some reason you can create a [transformer](https://glue.tidyverse.org/articles/transformers.html):

> Transformers allow you to apply functions to the glue input and output, before and after evaluation.

For example:

```r
newline_transformer <- function(regex = "[*]$", ...) {
    function(text, envir) {
        replace <- grepl(regex, text)
        if (replace) {
            text <- sub(regex, "", text)
        }
        res <- identity_transformer(text, envir)
        if (replace) {
            gsub("\\s+", "\n", x = res)
        } else {
            res
        }
    }
}
```

This will apply the transformer to any glue blocks ending in `*`. Then to use it:

```r
s <- c(
    "hello world hello world",
    "here are spaces",
    "they are great"
)

glue("{s*}", .transformer = newline_transformer())
[1] "hello\nworld\nhello\nworld" "here\nare\nspaces"          "they\nare\ngreat"
```

This is fun but it's a ludicrously convoluted approach - would not recommend.